# Vaadin lazy loading with Spring REST

Tags: spring, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin4spring

In my  Vaadin  web application I need to display 10,000+ user Information in a Table(or Grid) . The User information  displaying in UI is retrieved from our own  Spring REST web Service.

How Can I achieve this? ...

Thanks

Comment: How is it retrieved (exactly)?

Comment: That web service returns an ArrayList of User objects

Comment: could you please add what you already have tried e.g. code? As of know it is (to me) not even clear, what the concrete problem is. Are you paging at the REST level and need to mirror that into the lazy loading of the table? ...

Comment: @chathura *sigh* XML, JSON etc. Provide some code m8

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Steps: 
1. Read the list of users from your REST service. 
2. Created a GRID and attache the BeamItemContainer of User to it.

Grid will take care of displaying the users. You don't have to do anything special for lazy loading. grid will take care of it by displaying only required rows on UI and fetching it lazily at component level.

P.S : Grid is very smooth while loading the data on scroll than table. If you have too many rows prefer grid over table.

Comment: I am sorry but you fail at step 1: you cannot simply 'read list of users' if the list is too long. You have to code for effective memory management and caching. `Grid` only optimizes client-server communication.